# Teradata SQL tuning. Rewriting multiple left outer joins

Tags: sql, database, join, teradata, database-performance

I can see there is a  difference in the amount of rows but I am still not able to understand & account for it.

```
    sel  a.15 ,b.16 , c.17, d.18 from
     a LOJ b on (a.1=b.1 and a.2=b.2 and a.3=b.3 and a.4=b.4 and a.5=b.5 ) 
     LOJ c on ( a.1=c.1 and a.2=c.2 and a.3=c.3 and a.4=c.4  and  a.5=c.5) 
     LOJ d on ( a.6=d.6 and a.7=d.7 and a.3=d.3  and a.4=d.4)
   group by 1,2,3,4
```

Table  `a` is a billion + row fact table and PI  keys of  `a`  are nowhere participating on the join but `b` and `c's` PI keys are present in the joins and some  PI keys of `d` too.
So I rewrote as

```
select < same keys > 
  from a LOJ ( select  <keylist here>   from 
                b JOIN c 
                 on 
                (b.1=c.1 and b2.=c.2 and b3=c.3 and b4=c.4 and  b.5=c.5)
                 JOIN d 
                 on ( b.3=d.3 and and b.4=d.4)
                ) e 
                 on 
                 ( e.1=a.1 and e.2=a.2 and e.3=a.3 and e.4=a.4 
                 and e.5=a.5 and e.6=a.6 and a.7=e.7 )
               group by <col list>
    /*DT e created that joins b c and d.Though I joined on 3 and 4 before 
   with b and d I took them again in the derived table e 
   and used them again to improve query efficiency */
```

The above query runs a ton faster - 1/4th Impact CPU and  > 50% off the spool but
I see the  small row count difference. So my logic was  `a` was LOJ with these tables `b,c,d` separately. The rewrite will give `a` just 1 single table to LOJ with ... kind of confluence of `b,c,d`  ( a 'fused table' , if you will ). How does it matter to  `a` if it LOJ separately or joins to 1 single table.  But it does - I am loosing rows and I want understand how . I understand IJ's can be rewritten like this but LOJ's aren't the same. There is a SMALL difference in count (*) - some 15 rows / million. Well my question is what modifications do I add to the 2nd query so those 15 rows ( the delta ) can also be included and the queries are equivalent. 

Well on after thoughts after seeing this  again.. I do understand how they can give  varying results  ( because I am LOJ'ing `a` separately thrice )but  my Question was what should I add to 2nd to make it equivalent to the 1st.

Answer (score 1):

Your two queries are not the same.

Take a look at first query. 
In it, a joins all records in b initially. This also gives all records in a, even though it is not present in b, due to left join. This result set is then left joined with c. Again all records in 'a' are retrieved. Same goes in join between d and a. Here, b, c and d are independent of each other.

However, in your second query, you perform inner joins between b and c. This effectively means only rows whose keys are present in **both** b and c are fetched. Again this result set is **INNER** joined with d, which results in loss of few records. It is this end product which you left join with a. The records are lost in the subselect itself.

You are observing a small difference right now, because most of the records may have got their matches during inner join. However, your optimization diverges from the original approach.

Comment: Yes  A is in a left outer join.... in the first as well as the second query. In the second query it left outer joins on the composite cable

Comment: my 2nd Q was what modifications can I add to the 2nd Q to make it equivalent to the 1st

Comment: @user1874594: You can't modify Q2 to get the same result as Q1 (and even for Inner Joins your rewrite might not return the same result)

Comment: Hi Dieter For IJ's ( that is if the `a` table was Inner Joined instead of LOJ'ed ) how can the result differ ? wont transitive property apply  A join B  Join C  Join D on the same columns . I can join  B C and D - make a  `dt` table and join to A. Shouldn't i get the same result ? join cols being the same  . Also there was something I did to convet LOJ's to  IJ... sometime ago..  its not pure  IJ ..it'll help the LOJ  work  quicker if the left side non matches are few.. have to recollect

Comment: @user1874594: You `JOIN d 
                 on ( b.3=d.3 and and b.4=d.4)` which might result in more/different rows than joining on all four columns.

Comment: @user1874594, what are the relative sizes of b, c and d. Did we think of full outer join on these tables, or is it intimidating?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention. I did try `FULL JOIN` `b , c, & d` also and the result was in fact the same as `b c & d` `inner join` I ended up going the `vt` route , which per se isn't the 1st choice but still did the job. What Dieter pointed out is worth considering  `b` only partially offers cols that `a` and `d` are joined on -  `3 & 4`. For `7 & 6` cols I have to go back to`a` and join.